# Getting strange distortion with bandpass filter, what could be issue?

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I am trying to bandpass filter an EEG signal, nothing fancy but it's coming out pretty distorted. EEG data is taken from forehead. Sampling rate is 250 Hz. Cutoff is 2.5 Hz & 120 Hz.

Tried in both matlab & python, getting same results.

Matlab code:

```
data = load("rawdata.mat");
data = data.data;
figure
bandpass(data,[2.5 120],250)
```

[Matlab filtered data, click here to see plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItGAe.png)

Here is the python code:

```
Fs = 250
lowcut = 2.5
highcut = 120
order=5

plotbutterworth(lowcut, highcut, Fs, order)

plt.figure()
fr, y_m = Fourier(250, data)
plt.stem(fr, y_m, use_line_collection = True)
plt.title('Freq CH7')
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude (microvolts)")

filtered = butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, Fs, order)

plt.figure()
fr, y_m = Fourier(250, filtered)
plt.stem(fr, y_m, use_line_collection= True)
plt.title('Freq CH7 -- without EKG')
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude (microvolts)")

plt.figure()
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(filtered)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude (microvolts)")
plt.legend(['original','filtered'],loc='best')
```

[Python butterworth bandpass filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khQxK.png)

[fft of original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWmIh.png)

[fft of filtered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcu2Y.png)

[raw & filtered data in time domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY1yY.png)

Have tried changing cutoff frequencies slighting so less close to edge (like 5Hz and 110 Hz) but haven't found any noticeable improvement

Comment: What is the distortion you’re having trouble with? You need to be very explicit about everything, we don’t know what you know, only what you write here. Are you perhaps talking about the wild swinging at the two ends of the filtered signal? That’s a boundary condition problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove DC offset by subtracting mean!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).